# How to make responsive absolute positioning element with css/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div tag with a background image that has css animation when the page loads: two borders will open up from the center of the div tag, then the background image appears after a second when the border animation is over. The two borders' position are absolute. I'm having an issue where when I scale down the browser, the background image scales down (which is what I wanted) but the two borders stay at the same position. I want the two borders to change the position when the browser scales up or down so that the background image div stays in between them. Anyway to do this with css or with jquery? Here's a rought idea of what I have:

```css
.background-img {
  width: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: fading-in;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.borders {
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 width: 8px;
 background-color: blue;
 height: 50px;
 border-radius: 4px;
}

.left-vertical-border {
 animation-name:move-left;
 animation-duration: 2s;   
 animation-timing-function: ease-in;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;    

}

.right-vertical-border {
 top: 8px;
 animation-name:move-right;
 animation-duration: 2s;
 animation-timing-function: ease-in;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
}

@keyframes move-left {
 from{transform: translateX(0px);}
 to{transform: translateX(-100px);}
}

@keyframes move-right {
 from{transform: translateX(0px);}
 to{transform: translateX(100px);}
}

@keyframes fading-in {
 from{opacity:0;}
 to{opacity:1;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head> 
  <title>Responsive Absolute Positioning using css/jquery</title>  
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="left-vertical-border borders"></div>
  <div class="background-img">fake bg image</div>
  <div class="right-vertical-border borders"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: use em instead of px and even still if you don't get desired effect then use media queries..

Comment: I would suggest you to try a different approach. Take a div, animate its width ( or max-width ) from 0 to 100%. You can keep the borders as 2 spans or pseudo-elements. Then, using transition-delay, you can fadeIn the image inside the div after the width animation has completed.

Answer (score 0):

To use position absolute. Parent div must have property position relative.
In your css I haven't seen position relative. In that case it might give problem